# Function mapping challange

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, functions, discrete-mathematics

> For a given set $A=\{1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots, n\}$, find the number of non-constant
>   mappings (associations ) $f$ from $A$ to $A$ such that $f(k) \leq f(k + 1)$
>   and $f(k) = f(f(k + 1))$.

This is the text of the problem.
But I don't understand how can we have $f(k)$, when we are not given a function?

Constant mapping is a mapping $f$ such that for some **C**, $f(k)$=**C** for all **k**. Thanks to @ferson2020 for explanation

Comment: A constant mapping is a mapping $f$ such that for some $c$, $f(k) = c$ for all $k$. So for instance, $f(1) = f(2) = \ldots = f(n) = 5$ would be a constant mapping.

Comment: You’re supposed to *find* the functions that satisfy the requirements. For example, if $n=2$, you can have $f(1)=f(2)=2$: $f(1)\le f(1+1)$, since in fact both are equal to $2$, and $f(f(1+1))=f(f(2))=f(2)=2=f(1)$, so both conditions are met.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That example wouldn't work since it would be a constant mapping.

Comment: @ferson2020: It won’t work for the problem, but it illustrates what is meant by satisfying the other requirements.

Comment: +1: for altering the question with info you learn from the comments

Comment: I'll give you a hint: there are no such non-constant mappings, so the answer is zero, but explaining it might be a bit tricky.

Comment: @ferson2020, perhaps I am missing something obvious, but what about $A = \{1,2,3\}$, with $f(1) = f(2) = 1$ and $f(3) = 2$?

Comment: @Mees de Vries the question is can you have a function f(1)=f(2)=1, that is not a constant one?

Comment: @user74028, my function $f$ is given by $f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 1$ and $f(3) = 2$ -- these three equations together describe $f$. Then $f$ is not a constant function, because it takes two different values, namely 1 and 2.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Oh my mistake; I thought I had a proof that such a function would have to be constant, but your example definitely works.

Comment: A quick and dirty programming exercise gives `[0,0,1,4,10,20,35,56,84,120,165,220,286]` as the number of functions for $n \in \{1,\ldots,13\}$, which certainly has a nice pattern: the differences between two consecutive pairs seems to give the triangular numbers in order. I do not see any obvious proof. @user74028, are you quite sure you've copied the question correctly? I vaguely recall having solved an exercise similar to this one years ago, with the outcome being that no such functions existed.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Your comment below is correct. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: For anyone interested in some small examples, here are all functions satisfying the constraints for $n = 5$ (for smaller $n$, simply ignore the latter values) represented as lists of pairs: [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,2)] [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,3)]
[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,4)]
[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,4)]
[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,3),(5,4)]
[(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4)]
[(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,3)]
[(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,4)]
[(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4)]
[(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3),(5,4)]
(edit: it seems the comments are not so suited for this purpose, but it's not an answer.)

Comment: @MeesdeVries  This list gives  3 functions when $n=3$ namely $[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[2,2,3]$, rather than 1 function as in your "quick and dirty" program result of previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can describe the allowable sequences as follows. For some constant $k$ and a value of $r<n$ we have $f(x)=k$ for $1 \le x \le r$, while $f(x)>k$ for $x>r.$ (We need $r<n$ here to avoid a constant sequence.) So far this satisfies $f(x)=f(f(x+1))$ since it is constant. Now consider what happens if we define $f(r+1)=y.$ Then from 
$$k=f(r)=f(f(r+1))=f(y)$$
we see that $y \le r$ (only the first $r$ integers of $\{1,...,n\}$ map to $k$), and at the same time we have $y>k$ since $r$ is the greatest integer mapping to $k$ and $y=f(r+1).$ We thus have, for choices of the value $y$, the only restriction
$$k+1 \le y \le r.$$
So there are $r-k$ choices for $y$. We also note that we have $k<r$ by combining the above $k<y$ and $y \le r$.

Once the map is defined on $[1,r+1]$ by mapping $[1,r]$ to $k$ and $r+1$ to one of the choices for $y$, the values of $f$ for $r+2,...,n$ are all determined by use of $f(x)=f(f(x+1))$ and in this range $f(x)=x-1$ is forced.

So we need to add, for all choices of $k,r$ with $1 \le k<r<n$, the number of choices $r-k$ for the value of $y$.

Then the number of maps is the double sum
$$\sum_{r=2}^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{r-1}(r-k).$$
The inner sum here is $\binom{n}{2},$ and summing that gives the final count as
$\binom{n}{3}$

Comment: You said the "This list gives 3 functions when n=3", but your sum also gives 1 function. I don't think that [1,1,3],[2,2,3] are solutions to n=3. Because for example in first pair f(2)=1,f(3)=3; f(2) < f(2+1), but f(2) != f(f(3))

Comment: I agree. Only one when $n=3$ namely $[1,1,2]$. In my terms here $r=2$ and $k=1$, and $f(3)$ must be between $k+1$ and $r$ which makes it $2$. Your "quick and dirty" program indeed does give the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{3}$.

Comment: Oops, the "quick and dirty" program was in the comment from Mees de Vries. Sorry for the misattribution. :(

Comment: Excellent! It's a shame I didn't look at some larger examples of functions, or I might have figured it out. I'm surprised by how complex the proof is for how simple the constraints and the outcome.

Comment: @coffeemath Can you explain this **f(x)=f(f(x+1))** ain't this true only if **1 ≤ x < r**? And **f(r)=f(f(r+1))**, when we don't know what is **f(r+1)**?

Comment: As stated in the problem, $f(x)$ is a function from $A$ to $A$, and the relation $f(f(k+1))=f(k)$ only makes sense if $k+1 \le n$ since $f(k)$ is only defined for $1 \le k \le n$. So the $k$ of the relation must be restricted to $1 \le k \le n-1$. Another way to look at it is that the $r$ i use in my answer, if it were $n$, would make $f$ a constant map, which is ruled out by what the problem is counting, it diesn't count constant maps. Look again at the definition of $r$.